# Set various part of image clickable for various events

Tags: android, image, onclick

I am developing an app in which I want to use an image, which is slightly complicated.

I have searched through internet and found some answers like creating maps and defining co-ordinates for rectangle, circle or such shapes.

I have also tried with "`android:rotation`" property, but didn't get the perfect results.

But, my need is something different.

I am also attaching the link of the sample image.
I want to **`tag`** these 3 part of image **to different activities**.

[image: http://tinyurl.com/image-for-android]

Comment: Make the image the background of a relative layout.  Add buttons to the relative layout so that they are positioned how you want them.  Style the buttons to be invisible.  Use the onClick handlers.

Comment: Thanx @Simon, I thought the same but do you think that one can create such shaped buttons?

I mean the shape is too wierd.